# Floating analog input using Arduino with 1m cable

Tags: arduino, analog, piezo, floating, floating-pin

I use an analog input from an Arduino to read the value from a piezo plugged in parallel with a 1M ohm resistor.

I followed this tutorial from Arduino: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Knock

**Here is my schematic:**

[image]

It worked perfectly until I decided to use a 1m cable between the piezo scheme (piezo || resistor) and the analog input.

With a short cable, I read 0 when there was no vibration nor activity. But when I change the length to 1m, I always read values higher than 0... This input is floating.

What would be the solution so I can read a precise value and stop this input from floating?

Comment: I suspect you will need a piezo pre-amp that will condition the signal for transmission. They aren't complicated. But given the high impedance of the piezo, looking probably at a JFET pre-amp.

Comment: @jonk, Thanks a lot for this comment I'm going to take a look !

Comment: The first search I did produced this [jfet preamp for piezos](https://www.zachpoff.com/resources/alex-rice-piezo-preamplifier/). However, this one uses the phantom power used in XLR microphones and wouldn't be appropriate for your use here. But it gives you an idea. And it is a pretty fancy design. I'm kind of curious about studying it more carefully. Anyway, you'd be considering something much easier, I think. More like what's used with electret microphones, I think. So include jfet and electret in your searches, too.

Comment: @jonk I found this simple schematic http://hackaweek.com/hacks/?p=365 the BOM looks lighter than the XLR example. I will replace the 12V by 5V and try it! Thanks for all the hints!

Comment: Once I preamp the piezo signal. Should I put a pull-down resistor near the analog input ?

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake I think you should experiment a bit unless you feel able to do the design, yourself. That schematic you found is more like what I was thinking about. You may not require anything additional at the MCU end. But a DC path at the MCU end is probably a good idea. So you might try your 1 Meg idea just to provide something simple there. Just a series capacitor alone is probably not as good. So yeah. Add something.

Comment: It is important to know what you actually want to amplify, i.e. what is the nature of the signal that actually contains the information. In a piezo sensor that is charge.
You amplify charge with a charge amplifier which converts the charge generated in the piezo sensor into for instance a voltage. 
The simplest circuit for this is a well-biased low noise mos- or j-fet with low impedance gate capacity and negative feedback through a capacitor between drain and gate which is much larger than the drain-gate parasitic capacitance.
The smaller this capacitor, the larger the amplification.

Comment: So there's a trade-off. You could bias the mosfet through a high impedance low noise resistor voltage divider, put a resistor in the source and decouple that with a large enough capacitor. If however the frequency of the signal you want to measure is much lower than 50 or 60 Hz, depending on where you live--because I suspect that kind of interference is bothering you, you could be well served with just putting a capacitor along the input to filter out the 50/60 Hz noise induced in your cable. It might also help to twist your wire in order for the net flux being picked up is much lower.

Comment: The \$ R C \$ time of the filter should be (much?) lower than \$ 20 \$ or \$ 16.7 \, ms \$. Say you make it \$ 5 \, ms \$, then with your \$ 1 \, M \Omega \$ resistor, the input capacitor will be \$ 20 \, ms/1 \, M \Omega = 20 \, \mu F \$. And don't forget to decouple the input for DC with a capacitor. An example can be found here: www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa033a/sloa033a.pdf (charge mode amplifier) or here: www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu765/tidu765.pdf .

Comment: @joe electro, I like the charge mode amplifier from TI. I'm gonna order the components today and give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the designs I see in the comments seem overkill for what you are trying to do (BTW: you do realize you are applying negative voltages to your µC, right?). A very simple amplifier could do the trick.

Try this configuration, which is powered from the remote bias node on the µC side:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbiQ5F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the gain is excessive for your application or you want to DC-couple to the piezo, you can add a resistor on the source of the FET and/or remove C2.

Comment: I don't see where am I applying negative ( - ) voltage to the uC? Could you explain?

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake the output of the piezoelectric sensor is capacitively coupled, so it swings both positive and negative. It is also high-impedance so it might not be problematic, however a good wack could also mean hundreds of volts and considerable energy so a protection zener might be advisable.